# Reading out XML serves unexpected output in C++

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

I have a question about reading from a XML file.

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <level>
       <terrain name="terrain" mesh="terrain.x" texture="terrain.bmp" position="011"></terrain>
       <skybox name="skybox" mesh="skybox.x" left="left.jpg" right="right.jpg" bottom="bottom.jpg" top="top.jpg" back="back.jpg" front="front.jpg" position="111"></skybox>
       <entity name="tiger" mesh="tiger.x" texture="tiger.bmp" position="000"></entity>
</level>
```

My code:

```
rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
rapidxml::xml_node<>* root;

std::ifstream file("level\\noob.xml");

    std::vector<char> buffer((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    buffer.push_back('\0');

    doc.parse<0>(&buffer[0]);

    root = doc.first_node("level");

    for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* terrain = root->first_node("terrain"); terrain; terrain = terrain->next_sibling())
    {
        std::cout << terrain->first_attribute("name")->value() << std::endl;
    }
```

So I only want to print the name of the terrain. But the outcome when running is this:

```
terrain
skybox
tiger
```

I check for the node "terrain" but it still prints the nodes "skybox" and "tiger". How?

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop start from node "terrain" and proceeds to the siblings, which are skybox and tiger.

Comment: Oh. I thought it would search for other "terrain" siblings. Is there a way to read each terrain, skybox or entity individually without interfering eachother?

Comment: change this:-  `terrain = terrain->next_sibling()` to this: `terrain = terrain->next_sibling("terrain")`